# uniswap v2: flashloan fee

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I know that there is a 0.3% fee in the flashloan of Uniswap v2, which is deducted from the transaction. When I use the swap () function for flashloans, in the end I should pay back the money. I need to calculate the fee, I see someone calculating it this way, and I cannot understand:

```
uint256 _ fee = (_amount * 3) / 997 + 1
```

[image]
This calculation is somewhat similar to the getAmountIn(), but not the same.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula and explanation can be found [here](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/guides/smart-contract-integration/using-flash-swaps#single-token) in the Uniswap docs.